# python can't run flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have satisfied flask dependencies as follows.

```
indikau@ruhuna ~ $ sudo -H python -m pip install flask
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous>=0.21 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): click>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
indikau@ruhuna ~ $ ls
```

And this is my code.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello() -> str:
    return 'Hello Flask!'

app.run()
```

I'm able to create a new virtualenv.

```
indikau@ruhuna ~/Documents/head_first_python/chapter04 $ virtualenv flask
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/indikau/Documents/head_first_python/chapter04/flask/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in /home/indikau/Documents/head_first_python/chapter04/flask/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
indikau@ruhuna ~/Documents/head_first_python/chapter04 $ which flask
/usr/local/bin/flask
```

But still I get the following error.

```
indikau@ruhuna ~/Documents/head_first_python/chapter04 $ python hello.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask'
```

Anyone can help me? (I'm on python3.x)

Comment: It looks like you have flask in the Python 2 directory, not Python 3. When you run Python 3, it will not have the Python 2 directory in your path

Comment: For example, this output: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)`

Comment: Anyway to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would use virtualenv, you must activate the virtual environment. execute below code after `virtualenv flask`:

```
source /home/indikau/Documents/head_first_python/chapter04/flask/bin/activate
```

and reinstall flask in the virtual environment flask.

Comment: `indikau@ruhuna ~ $ virtualenv flask`
`Using base prefix '/usr'`
`New python executable in /home/indikau/flask/bin/python3.5`
`Also creating executable in /home/indikau/flask/bin/python`
`Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.`
`indikau@ruhuna ~ $ source /home/indikau/Documents/head_first_python/chapter04/flask/bin/activate`
(flask)indikau@ruhuna ~ $ python hello.py 
python3: can't open file 'hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(flask) indikau@ruhuna ~ $`